# Tile map only rendering 1 layer when it should be 3

Tags: java, tilemap

I've been working on this for a while and I can not seem to figure it out. I had the fileParser() method in the constructor and it worked fine. Then I was told it's very bad practice to have it in the constructor. So I moved it to it's own method(which required making most of the variables static) and moved the call to the main Game class and now it runs without errors, but only my last layer is rendering. I've moved things in the class around. I've used more variables than there are at the moment. I've checked my files and they are for sure 32 by 32. So I have no clue why this is happening.

```
import com.stardust.main.gfx.Assets;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TileMap
{   
   private static final int TILE_SIZE = 32;
   //placeholder for each tile 
   BufferedImage[] tiles = new BufferedImage[37];

   //array of tile types
   private static int[][] map = new int[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE];
   //position coordinates
   private int posX, posY;
   //Edge of map Cooridinates
   public static int sx, sy;
   private String fileName;
   private static int x = 0, y = 0;

   public TileMap(int posX, int posY, String fileName) throws IOException
   {
       this.fileName = fileName;
       this.posX = posX;
       this.posY = posY;
       this.sx = map.length * TILE_SIZE;
       this.sy = map.length * TILE_SIZE;

       setTile();

   }

   public void render(Graphics g)
   {
       for(int x = 0; x < TILE_SIZE; x++)
       {       
           for(int y = 0; y < TILE_SIZE; y++)
           {
               int textureType = map[x][y];
               BufferedImage texture = tiles[textureType]; 
               g.drawImage(texture, posX, posY, null);
               posY += TILE_SIZE;
           }
           posX += 32;
           posY = Game.mapY;
       }
       posX = Game.mapX;
       posY = Game.mapY;

   }


   private void setTile()
   {
       tiles[0] = Assets.grass;
       tiles[1] = Assets.dirt;
       tiles[2] = Assets.water;
       tiles[3] = Assets.tree;
       tiles[4] = Assets.multiTree;
       tiles[5] = Assets.NSpath;
       tiles[6] = Assets.uprtPath;
       tiles[7] = Assets.EWpath;
       tiles[8] = Assets.upltPath;
       tiles[9] = Assets.dnltPath;
       tiles[10] = Assets.dnrtPath;
       tiles[11] = Assets.watgrsdn;
       tiles[12] = Assets.watgrslt;
       tiles[13] = Assets.watgrsup;
       tiles[14] = Assets.watgrsrt;
       tiles[15] = Assets.watgrsSE;
       tiles[16] = Assets.watgrsSW;
       tiles[17] = Assets.watgrsNW;
       tiles[18] = Assets.watgrsNE;
       tiles[19] = Assets.wallWood;
       tiles[20] = Assets.pointer;
       tiles[21] = Assets.pathOpRt;
       tiles[22] = Assets.pathOpLt;
       tiles[23] = Assets.pathOpDn;
       tiles[24] = Assets.pathOpUp;
       tiles[25] = Assets.pathOpAll;
       tiles[26] = Assets.roughWood;
       tiles[27] = Assets.pathOpen;
       tiles[28] = Assets.counter;
       tiles[29] = Assets.storeDude;
       tiles[30] = Assets.pot;
       tiles[31] = Assets.singleHouse;
       tiles[32] = Assets.doubleHouse;
       tiles[33] = Assets.wepBanner;
       tiles[34] = Assets.armBanner;
       tiles[35] = Assets.innBanner;
       tiles[36] = Assets.blankTile;
   }

   public void fileParser() throws IOException
   {
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

       String line;

       while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
       {
           String[] values = line.split(",");

           for(String str : values)
           {
               int str_int = Integer.parseInt(str);
               map[x][y] = str_int;
               ++y;
           }
           ++x;
           y = 0;
       }
       x = 0;

       in.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: When someone says you shouldn't have something in your constructor, just calling it from the constructor won't change anything. The basic idea is that (in your case) loading the tiles might fail, which could leave your object in a dirty state (since you can't really signal that loading failed from your constructor).

Comment: So should I call the function in my main Game class?

Comment: OK, I moved the function to my main Game class, but I am still having the same problem. Should I make a new question or edit the post and point that out?

Comment: If it's still the same question, just keep it or update your question. There's no need to ask the same question again. And forgot to ask: Where are you reading three layers and trying to draw three layers? I only see you iterating through one layer every time?

Comment: I made three separate objects for each layer. all from the same class. When the object is created, the fileParser() method (which I moved to the main class) reads the text file passed in the constructor (I have one text file for each layer) then the class takes care of rendering them with the render method of each object.

Comment: I didn't mean three objects for each layer. Just three objects, one for each layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map[][] is static so the three objects (layers) will access the same map (and overwrite it). You should make it nonstatic to allow each object to have it's own.

Secondly the fileParser() method is private so you will have to either make it public or call it inside the class.

Comment: I had already made the fileParser() method public, I just forgot to update that when I updated the post. Thank you though. So I have a problem. Without making the map[][] static, I cannot call use it in the fileParser() method. Do you have a suggestion of how to go about that?

Comment: The fileParser method is nonstatic so it should work. And by the way I think you should call it in the constructor, and only run the setTile method once (and make setTile() and 'tiles' static so that they belong to the class rather than the object)

Comment: Oh thank you so much!!! I would up vote you, but I don't have enough reputation. I was working on this for a while and every time I would re-write it, the IDE would tell me that I couldn't use map[][] without making it static.